# Show that $||(kI-T)^{-1}|| \le \frac{1}{d}$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

> Suppose that $T \in BL(H)$ where $H$ is a Hilbert Space. Let $k \in \mathbb{C}$. Let $d=\text{dist}(k,W(T)) \gt 0$. Define the numerical range of $T$ as $$W(T)=\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: \lambda=\langle Tx,x\rangle, \|x\|=1, x \in H\}.$$ Show that $\|(kI-T)^{-1}\| \le \frac{1}{d}$.

First of all I need to see that $(kI-T)^{-1}$ makes sense. Since $\sigma(T) \subset \overline{W(T)}$ and  $d=\text{dist}(k,\overline{W(T)}) \gt 0$, the inverse makes sense. Now I set out to find the solution.

My try: First of all I find relation between $W(T)$ and $W(T-kI)$. So if $\lambda \in W(T)$, then $\lambda=\langle Tx,x\rangle$ with $\|x\|=1$. Then $\langle Tx-kx,x\rangle=\lambda-k$. Hence $W(T-kI)=\{\lambda-k: \lambda \in W(T)\}$. The other way around can be proved similarly. Now,
\begin{align}
\|T-kI\|
& = \sup_{\|x\|,\|y\| \le 1 }|\langle Tx-kx,y\rangle | \\
& \ge \sup_{\|x\|=1}|\langle Tx-kIx,x\rangle | \\
& =\sup_{\lambda \in W(T-kI)}|\lambda| \\
& =\sup_{\mu \in W(T)}{|\mu-k|}
\ge d
\gt 0.
\end{align}

But after reaching here I am not able to go to its inverse. There might be some other way. I want to know if I can go from here

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What properties of numerical range do you know about at this point?

Comment: That $ w (T) $ is a norm and equivalent.

Comment: For example, do you know $W(T)$ is convex in a set type of sense?

Comment: The convexity of $W(T)$ is not a simple issue. That's why I was asking if you knew that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $k$, $d$ are as specified, then
$$
            d\|x\|^2 \le |k\|x\|^2-\langle Tx,x\rangle| \\
             d\|x\|^2 \le |\langle (kI-T)x,x\rangle| \le\|(kI-T)x\|\|x\| \\
                d\|x\| \le \|(kI-T)x\|.
$$
That's enough to give you injectivity of $kI-T$, along with a closed range. Then
$$
               \mathcal{R}(kI-T) = \mathcal{N}(\overline{k}I-T^{\star})^{\perp}
$$
However, the first inequality also gives you
$$
                  d\|x\|^2 \le |\overline{k\|x\|^2-\langle Tx,x\rangle}|
               = |\overline{k}\|x\|^2-\langle T^{\star}x,x\rangle| \\
                 d\|x\| \le \|(\overline{k}I-T^{\star})x\|.
$$
Therefore $\mathcal{R}(kI-T)=\{0\}^{\perp}=H$. So $kI-T$ is invertible.

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam : You need to back up a bit from you last steps. Don't be so quick to take the supremum over $x$ *and* $y$, just over $y$. But you can also use Cauchy-Schwarz as I've shown you.